# Can I prevent sphinx numpydoc to split the Returns into two sections

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc

When using sphinx numpydoc I document the Returns section.

```
Returns
-------
out: float
    A sentence about the return type
```

However, rendered this is split into two sections.

```
Returns:

    out - A sentence about the return type

Return type:

    float
```

How can I prevent this section to be split and only have a Returns section? Where the Returns section is rendered just as the Parameters section.

If this matters I am using the pydata sphinx theme.

Comment: The syntax requires a space on each side of the `:`. Try that. Reference: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#parameters

Comment: @StevePiercy That does not change anything. Removing out, so just a bare float, will also create a separate Return type section.